# Why is it saying this is not a json object?

Tags: java, api, object, gson, minecraft

i am new to json parsing and i'm trying to figure out why it's returning null.

Here is my java code (if you aren't familiar with the spigot api https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/overview-summary.html)

Can you tell me what i am doing wrong? i'll give the gson part of the code and then i'll give the rest. think of it as just outputting the json in a console if you don't feel like reading the api.

```
try {
                    URL hypixel = new URL("https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=apikey&name=" + username);
                    URLConnection urlConn = hypixel.openConnection();
                    urlConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
                    urlConn.getDoOutput();

                    try(final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()))) {
                        final JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

                        parser.parse(reader.readLine());

                        final JsonObject object = parser.parse("").getAsJsonObject();


                        String userId = object.getAsJsonObject("player").get("_id").getAsString();

                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "UID: " + userId);

                }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Something went wrong!");
                }
```

(p.sendmessage would be the thing going in console)

Here is all of the code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {

        Player p = (Player) sender;

        if(command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("hypixel")) {

            if(args.length == 2) {
            String username = args[0];



                try {
                    URL hypixel = new URL("https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=apikey&name=" + username);
                    URLConnection urlConn = hypixel.openConnection();
                    urlConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
                    urlConn.getDoOutput();

                    try(final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()))) {
                        final JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

                        parser.parse(reader.readLine());

                        final JsonObject object = parser.parse("").getAsJsonObject();


                        String userId = object.getAsJsonObject("player").get("_id").getAsString();

                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "UID: " + userId);

                }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Something went wrong!");
                }

                }   

        }

        return false;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated thank you!

(Oh and here is the part of the response from the api that i want to parse)

```
{"success":true,"player":{"_id":"5442f08f48b8f1e1e64a0400"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parser.parse("").getAsJsonObject()
```

is expecting `""` to be JSON, which it is not.